# Add data to collection before pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, pagination

I get some data from the database and do pagination with the following call:

```
$itemsList = DB::Table('items')->paginate(10);
```

Each item in the data has an expiry date associated with it, from which I calculate the number of days left and return as an array with a function I wrote. I need to somehow integrate this array into the pagination call in order for each page to display the correct days left value. At the moment, I have in my blade file something like this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
?>
@foreach ($itemsList as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->item_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->item_user }}</td>
        <td>{{$left_days[$i++]}}</td>
```

With this method the first page of pagination works fine, with the left_days array referring to the correct item in the list. On other pages however, the left_days values refer to the items of the first page, since the i value starts at 0 each run.

I think I need to add the left_days array into the collection before the pagination call, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

To be more specific, below is the result of dd on $itemList:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#292 ▼
  #total: 94
  #lastPage: 10
  #items: Collection {#277 ▼
    #items: array:10 [▼
      0 => {#276 ▼
        +"id": 1
        +"item_name": "sadasd"
        +"item_user": "sadas"
        +"expiry_date": "2019-06-26"
        +"last_modified_by": "someone"
        +"created_at": "2019-06-18 15:19:33"
        +"updated_at": "2019-06-18 15:19:33"
      }
      1 => {#270 ▶}
      2 => {#279 ▶}
      3 => {#280 ▶}
      4 => {#281 ▶}
      5 => {#282 ▶}
      6 => {#283 ▶}
      7 => {#284 ▶}
      8 => {#285 ▶}
      9 => {#286 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8000/licenses"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

What I think I need is having a way to insert my array at the right locations such that each item in the collection also has a filed left_days that is calculated prior to the pagination.

Comment: How about `{{ $item->left_days }}` and then in your model you add the method `public function getLeftDaysAttribute() { return 5; }`

Comment: @RolandStarke That would only work if they're using an `Item` model; using `DB::table("items")` generates `stdClass` objects, which can't have functions applied to them like models can. But if they use `Item::paginate(10);`, and `Item` model exists with that function, then it would work no problem.

Comment: @TimLewis I've called paginate with `Item::paginate(10);` and this seems to work. I haven't set a left_days variable anywhere though. How does this work?

Comment: That's the magic of `get{...}Attribute()` function of models. It translates whatever is in `{...}`, in this case `{LeftDays}`, into an accessible property.

Comment: Pretty cool. Now I need to figure out how to access the expiry_date variable inside this getLeftDaysAttribute function so I can do the calculation.

Comment: That's even simpler; `$this->expiry_date` :) `$this` references the current object, which in the case of a `Model`, is the current database row.

Comment: Figured it out  $this->expiry_date. Thanks for the help guys :D

Comment: @RolandStarke Feel free to add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Roland Starke and Tim Lewis:

Use:

```
Item::paginate(10);
```

instead of:

```
DB::Table('items')->paginate(10);'
```

and write a get function inside the model like this:

```
public function getLeftDaysAttribute(){
     calculations...
    return value;
}
```

After which I can simply call in the blade file the value of left_days:

```
 $item->left_days
```